# TestContainer: Could not find a working container runtime strategy

Tags: node.js, jestjs, ts-jest, testcontainers

I'm using TestContainer PostgresSql module for running jest tests with NodeJS. I installed the module and tried running the out of the box example [here](https://node.testcontainers.org/modules/postgresql/), but got the following error:
`Could not find a working container runtime strategy`. I have docker installed.

Here is my code:

```
   beforeAll(async () => {
       const container = await new PostgreSqlContainer().start(); // fails
       // do other stuff
   });
```

Comment: Could you try to start docker ? `sudo service docker start` and then retry also be sure that docker is installed on your machine

Answer (score 0):

Had to restart my postgres. `brew services start postgresql` on my mac.

Answer (score 0):

You may likely restart your Postgresql and Docker service using the required

On Windows:
https://www.commandprompt.com/education/how-to-restart-postgresql-server-on-windows/

On Linux:

```
sudo service postgresql status

sudo service postgresql start

systemctl start docker
```